# getaddrinfo: A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup

Tags: c, windows, sockets, winsock2

I'm getting this weird error from `getaddrinfo()` on Windows 10 when running the following C program:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4406cb031791afba29e5

Here is the relevant part of the code that calls `getaddrinfo()`:

```
  int error;
  socket_t sock;
  struct sockaddr_in addr;
  struct addrinfo ai_hints, *ai_result, *ai_cur;
  #ifdef _WIN32
    int wsa_error;
    WSADATA wsa_data;
  #endif

  if (argc < 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <host> <port>\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  #ifdef _WIN32
    wsa_error = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa_data);
    if (wsa_error != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup: %s\n",
          get_error_string(wsa_error, NULL, 0));
      return 2;
    }
  #endif

  puts("Hello, World!");

  sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  if (sock == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "socket: %s\n",
        get_error_string(get_socket_error(), NULL, 0));
    return 3;
  }

  memset(&ai_hints, sizeof(ai_hints), 0);
  ai_hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
  ai_hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
  ai_hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

  error = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &ai_hints, &ai_result);
  if (error != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", error);
    close(sock);
    return 4;
  }
```

Each time the program gets run it no matter what hostname and port I pass through the command line it outputs the following:

```
Hello, World!
getaddrinfo: A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup.
```

I've also written a corresponding server program and it worked great (checked with telnet!).

Can you see anything wrong with my code?

**EDIT:**

It appears to work fine on Linux, `getaddrinfo()` is not giving any errors there and the client is able to connect to my server.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in the debugger?

Comment: When `getaddrinfo()` fails, `gai_strerror(get_socket_error())` should be `gai_strerror(error)` instead.

Comment: On a separate note, there is no point in setting `ai_hints.ai_family` to `AF_UNSPEC` since only IPv4 addresses can be used with an `AF_INET` socket. `AF_UNSPEC` allows `getaddrinfo()` to report both  IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. If `getaddrinfo()` happened to return IPv6 addresses for the hostname, `connect()` would fail on them. So, `ai_hints.ai_family` should be `AF_INET` in this situation.  Also, the code is not calling `freeaddrinfo()` when finished using `ai_result`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Replacing `get_socket_error()` call with `error` didn't change anything unfortunately, still getting this error. I also changed the protocol family to `AF_INET` like you suggested but that didn't help (good to know though).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I think I was going to free the `getaddrinfo()` result as I kept it unchanged in `ai_result` but somehow forgot to do that, thanks!

Comment: @Ben: Yes, I've tried stepping through the code in the debugger, that didn't really help much except I was able to see the error code number.

Comment: I think I'll try to run the same program on a VM to see if anything changes, I suspect it could have something to do with my machine's configuration.

Comment: Here are two links that both suggest the problem could be your A/V software: http://steamcommunity.com/app/211500/discussions/1/828939797072266592/?l=english and http://www.gazchap.com/posts/getaddrinfo-failed-non-recoverable-error-database-lookup/

Comment: @paulsm4: Thanks, I've seen that, the problem is I don't have any antivirus installed, well except Windows Defender, but disabling it didn't help last time I tried :(

Comment: What are the actual values of `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`? Can you successfully ping the value of `argv[1]` on the command line? I would find it odd if ping succeeds but `getaddrinfo()` fails.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I'm passing `127.0.0.1` and `40000` but I had also tried other ports and hosts (`localhost` and `0.0.0.0` didn't work as well).

Comment: Thanks everybody, I finally found the solution! Check out the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hooray! I found it!

It turns out I messed up the order of arguments in `memset()` when initializing `ai_hints`, i.e. instead of:

```
  memset(&ai_hints, sizeof(ai_hints), 0);
```

it should have been:

```
  memset(&ai_hints, 0, sizeof(ai_hints));
```

Too bad I didn't read `getaddrinfo()` documentation fully, it described exactly this error condition:

> pHints [in, optional]
>
> A pointer to an addrinfo structure that provides hints about the type of socket the caller supports.
>
> The ai_addrlen, ai_canonname, ai_addr, and ai_next members of the addrinfo structure pointed to by the pHints parameter must be zero or
>   NULL. **Otherwise the GetAddrInfoEx function will fail with
>   [WSANO_RECOVERY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WSANO_RECOVERY)**.

Comment: For exacting this reason, you might want to consider getting in the habit of using `= {0}` for struct initializations instead of using `memset()`, eg: `struct addrinfo ai_hints = {0};`